# Unable to hit https (SSL connection) request from remote machine with proxy application

Tags: browser, ssl, https, proxy, firewall

We have one proxy application (VB6 app) on one machine (Server machine) in LAN.
And all other machine hits to that machine's proxy through browsers settings for proxy application.
Http calls from all machines works fine.
If I hit any https request in browser from my local its works fine, but if I hit it from other machine from LAN (remote machine) it give me an different errors at different time like

1. Secure Connection Failed
   An error occurred during a connection to www.onlinesbi.com.
   SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
   (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
2. The connection was interrupted
   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
   moments.
   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
   connection.
   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
   that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

3.
Proxy refusing a connection.

Is there any setting in browser, windows firewall or any other to allow to hit https request(or allow SSL connection) from remote machine?